# Errors in windows task scheduler while trying to schedule auto download and backup of database from remote server to local server with php script

Tags: php, ssl, ftp, database-backups, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to auto sync my remote database with my local machine by using php file_get_contents and connecting to remote server with ftp_connect frequent intervals. I am using windows Task Scheduler from my local machine for that.

My php script works perfectly from the browser. But when Task Scheduler Triggers it, the command prompt window comes up showing error messages.

My script is

```
    <?php 
    set_time_limit(0);
    include('functions.php');
    $root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $sitearr=array("indianchristians","mc","evaa","laveena","aita","kaazar","landshop");
    $date=Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $vals="";
    $msg="";

    foreach($sitearr as $sa)
        {
            include('connnew.php');
            if($sa=="landshop")
                {
                    $remurl="dwggxtwa_landshoppe.sql";
                    $localurl="$root/$folder/Myadmin/download/sqlbackup/";
                     
   $backupserv=file_get_contents($url."/Myadmin/download/sqlbackup/backupserver.php");  
                }
                else{
                    $remurl="$db.sql";
                    $localurl="$root/$folder/admin/download/sqlbackup/";
                     
   $backupserv=file_get_contents($url."/admin/download/sqlbackup/backupserver.php");
                }
                $savedb=$db.".sql";
                $localdb=$localurl.$savedb;
    //          echo $localdb."<br>";

                $conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
                $login_result = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
                ftp_pasv($conn, true);
                if($sa=="landshop"){
                    ftp_chdir($conn, '/public_html/Myadmin/download/sqlbackup/');
                }else{
                    ftp_chdir($conn, '/admin/download/sqlbackup/');
                }
                if (ftp_get($conn, $localdb, $remurl, FTP_BINARY)) 
                {
    //                  echo "$sa saved locally<br>";
                $query=$maindb->query("SHOW TABLES") or die("SHOW TABLES ERROR ".$maindb->error);
                        
                    while($st=$query->fetch_array()){
                        $drop=$maindb->query("DROP TABLE $db.$st[0]");
    //if($drop){echo "<br>$db.$st[0] DROPPED !<br>";}else{echo "<br>$db.$st[0] NOT DROPPED ! 
   <br>";}
                    }
                    $templine = '';
                    // Read in entire file
                        $lines = file($localdb);
                    // Loop through each line
                    foreach ($lines as $line)
                    {
                        // Skip it if it's a comment
                        if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
                            continue;

                        // Add this line to the current segment
                        $templine .= $line;
                        // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
                        if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
                        {
                            // Perform the query
                            if(!empty($templine)){
                                $maindb->query($templine) or die('Error performing query 
    \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . $maindb->error . '<br /><br />');
                            }
                            // Reset temp variable to empty
                            $templine = '';
                        }
                    }
                    ftp_close($conn);
                                
                $vals.="('$date','$sa'),";
                $msg .="Updated $sa<br>";

                }
        }

            if(!empty($vals)){
                $vals=rtrim($vals,",");
                $date=Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','admin','admin') or die ("Error connecting to 
    mysql : " . mysqli_connect_errno($link).'\r\n');
                $connect=new mysqli('127.0.0.1','admin','admin','admin') or die("Database error 
    :".$connect->error);
                
                $checktab=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM backuptimeline");
                    if(!$checktab)
                    {
                        $createsql = "CREATE TABLE backuptimeline
                         (
                             id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                             PRIMARY KEY(id),
                             Date datetime,
                             site varchar(500)
                         )";
                        $createtab=$connect->query($createsql) or die($connect->error);
                    }
                        $butlsql="INSERT INTO backuptimeline (Date,site) VALUES $vals";
    //              echo $butlsql."<br>";
                    $insbu=$connect->query($butlsql)or die($connect->error);
                    if($insbu){
                        //sendEmailAlerts("anitgopinath@gmail.com","anitgopinath@gmail.com","DB 
    $sa Backed Up","All DB $sa backed up at $date");
                        $msg.="<br>Timeline Updated<br>";
                    }       
                    else{
                        $msg.= "<br>Timeline Not Updated<br>";
                    }   
                    echo $msg."<br>";
                    sendEmailAlerts("anitgopinath@gmail.com","anitgopinath@gmail.com","DBs Back Up 
    Results",$msg);
            }else{
                    echo $msg."<br>";
                    sendEmailAlerts("anitgopinath@gmail.com","anitgopinath@gmail.com","DBs Back Up 
    Failed",'DBs Back Up Failed');
            }

?>
```

Task Scheduler entries;

Program / Script in Action field:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\binaries\php\php_runningversion\php.exe"

Arguments field

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php"

Some error Messages

> Warning: ftp_get(/matrimony/admin/download/sqlbackup/rotiraa1_mc.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php on line 35 PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Error opening /matrimony/admin/download/sqlbackup/rotiraa1_mc.sql in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php on line 35
>
> Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening
> /matrimony/admin/download/sqlbackup/rotiraa1_mc.sql in C:\Program
> Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php
> on line 35 PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed
> with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1407742E:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version in
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php
> on line 21
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
> OpenSSL Error messages: error:1407742E:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version in
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php
> on line 21 PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
> in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php
> on line 21
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\Program
> Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php
> on line 21 PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(https://www.evaa-ethnix.com/admin/download/sqlbackup/backupserver.php):
> failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Admin\download\autobackup_task_scheduler.php
> on line 21
>
> Warning:
> file_get_contents(https://www.evaa-ethnix.com/admin/download/sqlbackup/backupserver.php):
> f

I have tried using a batch file (.bat) too. I put it in system32 folder and tried. Still same errors appear.

I am not able identify whether it is a path issue or something else. I have been breaking my for a long time on this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably using a different version of PHP and/or OpenSSL in browser and in Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after much googling and brainstorming I found I have two issues:

1. PHP file_get_contents was creating the SSL error. So I replaced it with Curl as follows;

   ```
          function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) {

                      $ch = curl_init();

                      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
                      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
                      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
                      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );

                      $data = curl_exec( $ch );
                      curl_close( $ch );

                      return $data;
            }
   ```
2. The path local url path ftp_get() began with a variable $root which had

> $root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

This was not seen by the Windows Task Scheduler. So I simply replaced $root with the complete path

> C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/$folder

All my problems disappeared ! My system is auto syncing my remote database to my local database on set schedules. I am a happy man now ! :)